# Does this series converge or diverge? And by which test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{2\ln n}$$
I use Dirichlet's Test as the following:
Since $\sum_{k=2}^{n}\cos k$ is bounded.
And the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{2\ln n}$ is decreasing to $0$.
Thus, the above series is convergent.
Right or wrong? Or have the methods.

Comment: It does converge by [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Comment: That is a correct use of Dirichlet's test, except you want $\sum_{n=2}^k \cos n$ rather than $\sum_{k=2}^n \cos n$.

Comment: Oh I confused and how can we use logarithm test ?

Comment: I have not heard of the logarithm test. Can you provide a link?

Comment: You can use cauchy condensation test.

Comment: Please help to tell me

Comment: @robjohn $$\lim _ { n \rightarrow + \infty } \frac { \ln ( \frac { 1 } { | a _ { n } | } ) } { \ln n } = l$$ If $l>1$, the series $a_n$ converges. If $l<1$, the series $a_n$ diverges.

Comment: @AmanPandey: this series is not positive and monotonically decreasing, so I don't think the [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) applies.

Comment: Yup.you are right.

Comment: @robjohn How can I call this test?. Because I knew it from the lecture that this is logarithm test.

Comment: @MartialGreen: The $p$-test says that if $|a_n|\le\frac{c}{n^p}$ for some $p\gt1$ then the sum converges, but if $|a_n|\ge\frac{c}{n^p}$ for some $p\lt1$, then the series diverges. Thus, the "log test" seems to be based on the the $p$-test. I don't know how many people would recognize the name "log test", but I have no other name for it.

Comment: @robjohn okay thank so much